# Transferring saved characters and/or worlds between different platforms

Tags: terraria

Is it possible to transfer Terraria characters and/or worlds between platforms? I am specifically asking about transferring from Xbox One to PC.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not possible. The console and PC versions are completely different game versions, and often differ in features and content. Therefore, it is not possible to load saved games (e.g. worlds or characters) from a different platform - even if it were possible to extract the data and put it on a different system.